# fabric.js object to string back to object not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I would like to be able to fetch my `fabric.js` canvas object and would need stringify it and then parse it back to an object. I set this canvas up to simulate taking the `fabric.js` line object to a string and parse back to a object. When I stringify I'm getting more data and get an error when adding it to the canvas.

```
<canvas id="demoCanvas"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
const myCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("demoCanvas", {
  backgroundColor: "beige",
});
const line = new fabric.Line([50, 100, 200, 100],{
    left: 160,
    top: 70,
    strokeWidth: 8,
    stroke: 8,
    padding: 12,
    angle: 90,
    //flipY: true,
    rotatingPointOffset: 92,
  });
console.log("first output", line);
const newLine = JSON.stringify(line);
console.log("string", newLine);
const newLine2 = JSON.parse(newLine);
console.log("back to obj", newLine2);
myCanvas.add(newLine2);
myCanvas.setActiveObject(newLine2);
</script>
```

I was expecting to get the same output as if I went straight from the `fabric.js` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting a `fabric.Line` object to a json string and expecting that parsing the string back will give you the same object, but that is not the case, what you get out of `JSON.parse` is a generic object not the original line.

What you can use is to stringify the options or the coordinates, that you can  parse and then reuse to create the new line, see the sample code below:

```js
const myCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("demoCanvas", {backgroundColor: "beige"})
const coords = [0, 0, 90, 90]
const options = {
  left: 90,
  top: 0,
  strokeWidth: 8,
  stroke: 8
}

console.log("first output", options)
const opt = JSON.stringify(options)
console.log("string", opt)
const opt2 = JSON.parse(opt)
console.log("back to obj", opt2)

const line = new fabric.Line(coords, opt2)
myCanvas.add(line)
```

```html
<canvas id="demoCanvas" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here is a simpler example of your problem, using the builtin Map object...

The first time around the get method works as expected, but after we stringify and parse a call to the get results in an error

```js
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set('a', 111);
map1.set('b', 222);
map1.set('c', 333);

console.log(map1.get('a'))
const x = JSON.stringify(map1)
const map2 = JSON.parse(x)
console.log(map2.get('a'))
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking. I thought I need to separate the fabric line object from from the options but was not sure how to go about it.